# How to omit undo step of component.addOperation during uninstall step in qt installer framework?

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I have componentscript in which I do mkdir and copydir operation during install as per the Qt Documentation http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/operations.html.  Internally, each operation has a DO step that contains instructions for the installer and an UNDO step that contains instructions for the uninstaller. I want the installer not to do the undo step during uninstall . I tried using following functions:

```
var path =installer.value("HomeDir") + "/AppData/Roaming/myfolder";    
component.addOperation("Execute", "mkdir", path, "UNDOEXECUTE", "del", "/S", "/F", path);   
component.addOperation("Execute", "cmd", "/C", "mkdir", path, "UNDOEXECUTE", "cmd ", "/C", "rmdir", "/S", /Q", path);
```

Executing this throws an error "Could not start: 'mkdir my/path'(No program defined) No such file or directory" . Is there any workaround to not to do undo operation of addOperation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to provide UNDO for every operation.

There are some predefined operations, you can use them directly as below

> component.addOperation("Mkdir", path);

or

> component.addOperation("Rmdir", path);

Or if you don't want UNDO operation at all, use below way to do the same

(For Windows OS)

> component.addOperation("Execute", "cmd", "/C", "mkdir " + path);

(For Linux OS)

> component.addOperation("Execute", "/bin/sh", "-c", "mkdir " + path);

Comment: I don't want the installer delete the folder which I created . If I do this component.addOperation("Mkdir", path); the installler deletes automatically

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: If you are executing mkdir with cmd, you should use + instead of comma in between mkdir command and path with propper spacing